# Store Raycast hit info

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

In my game, the player uses a virtual analog to aim towards a specific object, when he releases the analog the character should move towards that object. 
I want to store that object's position ( more like the direction where the player should move based on the object's position) in a variable but only if it was the last thing that the ray collided with:

```
Vector3 targetPos;

RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast (pos, dir, out hit, 10, targetLayer)) {

    Vector3 moveDir = (hit.point - transform.position).normalized;
    targetPos = moveDir;
} else {
    targetPos = Vector3.zero;   
}
```

By doing this the `targetPos` variable always returns to zero after releasing the analog even if the last collided objet was that specific object.

Edit:
Solved based on @MukeshSaini comment. Thanks, all.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Does your code ever go in the `if` statement? You can confirm by making a `BreakPoint` and debugging.

Comment: @Programmer, OP doesn't want the `targetPos` value to become zero after releasing the analog. @Abdou023, can you please share more code, I think you are using raycast even after the user released analog which might be returning false for `Physics.Raycast` and setting `targetPos` to `Vector3.zero` in `else` block.

Comment: @MukeshSaini Yes, you are right, raycast was being called even after the release of the analog. I managed to fix it based on your comment by adding a boolean check. You should make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using raycast even after the user released analog which might be returning false for `Physics.Raycast` and setting `targetPos` to `Vector3.zero` in `else` block.

You can put a condition to raycast only when user is using the analog which will stop the unnecessary else block to execute after user released the analog and `targetPos` will retain its correct value.